# On the std::abs function

Tags: c++, c++11, standards-compliance, absolute-value

Is the `std::abs()` function well defined for ALL arithmetic types in C++11 and will return `|x|` with no problem of approximation?

A weird thing is that with g++4.7, `std::abs(char)`, `std::abs(short int)`, `std::abs(int)`, `std::abs(long int)` and `std::abs(long long int)` seem to return a double (on the contrary of : http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/abs). And if the number is casted to a double, we could have some approximation error for very large number (like `-9223372036854775806LL = 2^63-3`).

So do I have the guarantee that `std::abs(x)` will always return `|x|` for all arithmetic types ?

EDIT : here is an example program to make some tests

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <cmath>
#include <typeinfo>

template<typename T>
void abstest(T x)
{
    static const unsigned int width = 16;
    const T val = x;
    if (sizeof(val) == 1) {
        std::cout<<std::setw(width)<<static_cast<int>(val)<<" ";
        std::cout<<std::setw(width)<<static_cast<int>(std::abs(val))<<" ";
    } else {
        std::cout<<std::setw(width)<<val<<" ";
        std::cout<<std::setw(width)<<static_cast<T>(std::abs(val))<<" ";
    }
    std::cout<<std::setw(width)<<sizeof(val)<<" ";
    std::cout<<std::setw(width)<<sizeof(std::abs(val))<<" ";
    std::cout<<std::setw(width)<<typeid(val).name()<<" ";
    std::cout<<std::setw(width)<<typeid(std::abs(val)).name()<<std::endl;
}

int main()
{
    double ref = -100000000000;
    abstest<char>(ref);
    abstest<short int>(ref);
    abstest<int>(ref);
    abstest<long int>(ref);
    abstest<long long int>(ref);
    abstest<signed char>(ref);
    abstest<signed short int>(ref);
    abstest<signed int>(ref);
    abstest<signed long int>(ref);
    abstest<signed long long int>(ref);
    abstest<unsigned char>(ref);
    abstest<unsigned short int>(ref);
    abstest<unsigned int>(ref);
    abstest<unsigned long int>(ref);
    abstest<unsigned long long int>(ref);
    abstest<float>(ref);
    abstest<double>(ref);
    abstest<long double>(ref);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What makes you think the g++ implementation is returning a double? Perhaps you could provide a sample of what you're doing that indicates a double is being returned?

Comment: Note that there are several `std::abs` in different headers, like `<cmath>` and `<cstdlib>`.

Comment: Of course `std::abs(x)` returns `|x|`. Perhaps you're wondering if `decltype(std::abs(x))` will match `decltype(x)`? I'm just a little confused by exactly what you mean by "will std::abs(x) always return |x|?"

Comment: I don't know what the C++ standard says, but such a guarantee is certainly impossible, since whenever `int` is a two's-complement signed integer, the absolute value of the minimum possible `int` is not representable as an `int`. (For example, if we have 32-bit integers, then the minimum possible value is -2,147,483,648, but the maximum possible value is only 2,147,483,647.)

Comment: I don't know about your gcc 4.7, but my gcc 4.7 calls `__gnu_cxx::abs`, which is an inline wrapper around `__x >= 0 ? __x : -__x;`

Comment: Could you post the output for your program? I don't have gcc 4.7.

Comment: Also see [Is std::abs(0u) ill-formed?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/29750946/1708801)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The correct overloads are guaranteed to be present in `<cmath>`/`<cstdlib>`:

C++11, [c.math]:

> In addition to the `int` versions of certain math functions in `<cstdlib>`, C++ adds `long` and `long long` overloaded versions of these functions, with the same semantics.
>
> The added signatures are:
>
> ```
> long abs(long);            // labs()
> long long abs(long long);  // llabs()
> ```
>
> [...]
>
> In addition to the `double` versions of the math functions in `<cmath>`, overloaded versions of these functions, with the same semantics.
>   C++ adds `float` and `long double` overloaded versions of these functions, with the same semantics.
>
> ```
> float abs(float);
> long double abs(long double);
> ```

So you should just make sure to include correctly `<cstdlib>` (`int`, `long`, `long long` overloads)/`<cmath>` (`double`, `float`, `long double` overloads).

Comment: Section 26.8.7-9 in case anyone cares.

Comment: why are the overloads separated? why not put all of them in one header file?

Comment: They follow the position of their corresponding C functions (`abs` and `fabs`), which I'm not sure it was a good idea, since more than once it happened to me not to import `<cmath>` and thus to use integer - abs over FP values.

Answer (score 5):

You cannot guarantee that `std::abs(x)` will always return `|x|` for all arithmetic types.  For example, most signed integer implementations have room for one more negative number than positive number, so the results of `abs(numeric_limits<int>::min())` will not equal `|x|`.

Comment: That looks like the only case, safe for `NaN`.

Comment: And it's the case the OP hits, as he converts the double -100000000000 to other types, truncating the value to the minimum limit in many cases.

Comment: @Kos  , int doesn’t have NaN.

Answer (score 1):

Check that you're in fact using `std::abs` from `<cstdlib>` and not `std::abs` from `<cmath>`.

PS. Oh, just saw the example program, well, there you go, you are using one of the floating point overloads of `std::abs`
.

Answer (score 0):

It's not weird that g++ (with C++11 standard) returns a double when you use `std::abs` from `<cmath>` with an integral type:
From http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cmath/abs/:

> Since C++11, additional overloads are provided in this header (`<cmath>`) for the integral types: These overloads effectively cast x to a double before calculations (defined for T being any integral type).

This is actually implemented like that in `/usr/include/c++/cmath`:

```
template<typename _Tp>
inline _GLIBCXX_CONSTEXPR
typename __gnu_cxx::__enable_if<__is_integer<_Tp>::__value,
                                double>::__type
abs(_Tp __x)
{ return __builtin_fabs(__x); }
```