# How can I avoid unexpected results from std::abs?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer

I've come across a few different examples of ways in which `std::abs` can give unexpected results:

1. This question ([On the std::abs function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13460750/on-the-stdabs-function)) points out that `<cstdlib>` provides overloads for integral types while `<cmath>` provides overloads for floating point types. Failing to include the correct header gives undefined behaviour, which the compiler is allowed to silently accept
2. C++ [Defect report 2735](https://cplusplus.github.io/LWG/issue2735) points out that the C++11 and C++14 standards technically require that `std::abs(short)` returns a `double`, although most compilers ignore the relevant wording and return an `int`. The resolution to this issue indicates that the wording was changed in C++17 so that `std::abs(short)` returns an `int`
3. The answers to this question ([When do I use fabs and when is it sufficient to use std::abs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3118165/when-do-i-use-fabs-and-when-is-it-sufficient-to-use-stdabs))  point out that relying on `std::abs` can lead to difficult-to-spot bugs, since (in modern C++) the headers which introduce `std::abs` are allowed to introduce a global `abs` function (which may or may not have the same overloads), and it's easy to accidentally use `abs` instead of `std::abs`

The fixes that I am aware of are:

1. Avoid undefined behaviour: include `<cstdlib>` if evaluating `std::abs([integral type])` and `<cmath>` if evaluating `std::abs([floating point type])`
2. Two options:

   - Use C++17 or pre-(C++11)
   - Work around the fact that `std::abs(short)` may return an `int` or a `double` depending on the compiler's compliance with the C++11/C++14 standard
3. Two options:

   - Pass gcc the flag `–Wconversion` so that calls like `abs(2.0)` trigger a warning at compilation
   - Use a trick (adapted from n.m.'s answer to ([Disable math.h crap when working with cmath](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19159541/disable-math-h-crap-when-working-with-cmath))) to make to the global `abs` ambiguous

Trick:

```
namespace neveruse{
    int abs(int);
}

using namespace neveruse;
```

**Question:** Is there a reason to prefer one of the solutions to issue 3 over the other? Do any of these fixes introduce other potential problems that I need to watch out for?

Comment: I often use `auto i_am_also_a_float = fabsf(i_am_a_float);`

Comment: Could you clarify exactly which defect you're trying to avoid. Is this question only asking about the problem with std::abs(short) returning doubles and ints? (Also which do you want?)

Comment: I'm interested in knowing whether either of the solutions to issue 3 is better, but also whether any of the solutions to issues 1 or 2 has side-effects that I might not have considered (such as making it easy to make other mistakes akin to forgetting std:: ).

Comment: I don't think, that the Trick is of any help, because it stops the ::abs(...) from beeing used, while the language defect affects std::abs(...)

Comment: "unexpected results from std::abs" include `abs(INT_MIN)`.

Answer (score 5):

Create a header file of your own that defines an `inline` function`absolute` that in turn includes all the correct headers and fixes bugs with return types, and calls `std::abs`.

Then, don't use `abs` or `std::abs` (or any token named `abs`).  Enforce this at git commit (or whatever version management system you are using) other than in that file.